Streamline in Photoshop, Illustrator, Actions, or a Script?
When I receive the artwork from my artist, I get a TIFF in a size that includes bleed (Fig 1). Every time I receive a new commission, I need several additional outputs of that file, so I am trying to come up with a more streamlined approach.

Files that I need with every commission:

Fig 2) Same size, adding a watermark
Fig 3) A web friendly-version that doesn't have the "bleed" art and has round corners (both hi-res PNG and a WEBP)
Fig 4) A new version that uses the PNG from (3) and creates a TIFF with bleed
Fig 5) A web friendly-version of (4) that doesn't have the bleed and has round corners (both hi-res PNG and a WEBP)

What are your thoughts on streamlining something like this? Right now I'm only doing 1-2 commissions per month, however, I'm looking at a 50+ commission for 2025 and doing this manually is quite tedious.

For figure 4 and 5, do you also need them to be placed on a new graphic with the black background? The first 3 can be achieved using Photoshop Actions.

Yes, it prints with a black background on that version.

If this were me, I would first set up a file with artboards in each of the required variations and use a smart layer so that when you change it on one artboard, it changes on all. Then, create an action for exporting in each of the required formats. I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways of doing this, for example via a script, but by using smart layers and actions you should be able to achieve the results you're after without needing scripting skills.
